# SQL French char encoding issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, encoding, french, string-decoding

I have an address with French chars - `Vétéran`. In table column it is read as `VÃ©tÃ©ran` when using SMS select. The server language is English.

When I copied `VÃ©tÃ©ran` to Word, it remained the same. I saved the Word doc as plain text using Windows default encoding (Western Europe), it is changed to `Vétéran`.

I cannot find a way to display it correctly in SMS. The data is copied from Oracle 12. It is displayed as `VÃ©tÃ©ran` by Oracle SQL Developer.

Need some help.

Thanks,

Will

I tried different case and accent setting in collate. Does not work.

Comment: What is the column type?

Comment: It is VARCHAR(MAX). It is the text of an XML file. I got it from a BLOB in Oracle.

Comment: So it already contains broken text.

Comment: I cannot say it is broken. Some software can display correctly. Word can change the junk chars to French. There is something I do not know.

Comment: They are not junk chars, they are [mojibake](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140930-00/?p=43953). Most likely UTF-8 interpreted as Latin1.

Comment: Try calling [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56181559/11683) on each such field, as in `select dbo.Convert_utf8(cast('VÃ©tÃ©ran' as varbinary(8000)))`.

Comment: A somewhat less mystical way to decode it with XML would be something like the following: `select cast('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + 'VÃ©tÃ©ran' as xml).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(50)');`. Probably the `encoding="utf-8"` DTD attribute wasn't included in the original XML file from Oracle, or some intermediate process stripped it out.

Comment: I got error when casting some rows to XML. There could be way to convert varbinary to utf8 directly without using XML.

Comment: Well, yes. Your fields contain binary utf-8 data that is being interpreted as ASCII. So you need to cast it to varbinary and process with a tool that can interpret the bytes as utf-8. You can make a dump, process with an external tool and import back. Or you could have a CLR function that accepts a varbinary and calls `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` on it.

Comment: I created a python program to do the fix. Not all lines are encoded wrong. Have to deal with those also.

def convertToUTF8(origText:str):
    try:
        UTF8Text=origText.encode("windows-1252").decode("utf-8")
        return UTF8Text
    except:
        return origText