# SQL Server and UTF-8 XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, unicode

I searched around and noticed some issues with SQL Server (I'm using 2017) and UTF-8.

From other threads I saw there is some data loss, if you directly use special characters in a XML, like emojis.

```
DECLARE @DT VARCHAR(MAX) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Name></Name>
'

DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = @DT

SELECT @XML 

-- Result: <Name>??</Name>
```

This is fine.

But when I use `<Name>ä</Name>` or `<Name>€</Name>` SQL throws an error:

```
Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
XML analysis: Line 2, character 7, invalid XML character.
```

Why does one lose memory, while others throw an error?

Comment: you mean: `<Name€>test</Name€>` ? you can read what's allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534945/allowed-symbols-in-xml-element-name

Comment: What collation is your database in? I *assume* it isn't a UTF-8 Collation, as if you were, the problem [does not occur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCXwd.png). For an ASCII code page, it is completely expected behaviour for `` to resolve to `??`; the character cannot be represented.

Comment: You're using ASCII, not Unicode strings. Your query fails in all cases and mangles the text. Use Unicode strings instead by adding the `N` prefix, the way all SQL Server docs and samples show. This has nothing to do with UTF8, it's about ASCII vs Unicode

Comment: Use the Unicode type `nvarchar` instead of the ASCII type, `varchar` too. If you get an error complaining about switching encodings, remove `encoding="utf-8"`. SQL Server always supported Unicode without having to resort to encodings. Unicode strings and types use UTF16

Answer (score -1):

This behaviour is completely expected. Putting Something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the start of a **literal string** does *not* change the collation of said *literal string*, and that literal string you have is a **`varchar`**. I don't know what collation you are in, but if you were in a UTF-8 collated database you would not have the problem. That you aren't, however, means that, of course, a character like  can't be represented as it flaws well outside the ASCII character range.

If you can't use a UTF-8 database, then you'll need to define your literal string and variable as an `nvarchar`. Then, when you set the value of the `@XML` variable, you need to `COLLATE` and `CONVERT` the value to a UTF-8 collation and `varchar`:

```sql
DECLARE @DT nvarchar(MAX) = N'<Name></Name>';

DECLARE @XML xml;
SET @XML = CONVERT(varchar(MAX),'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + @DT COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8);

SELECT @XML;
```

Comment: `does not change the collation of said literal string` - that is correct, but it may still have an effect on the [parsing of that literal string into XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56182378/11683).

Comment: @GSerg in the question's examples it will throw an error complaining about switching encodings

Comment: Just to validate Panagiotis' comment, @GSerg : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bdZPrGmS)

Answer (score -1):

All the queries in the question fail. All mangle the text because they use ASCII string literals that are saved in ASCII types. SQL Server always supported Unicode through Unicode types like `nvarchar` and Unicode literals. There's no reason to play with encodings.

This query works fine and doesn't mangle the text

```
DECLARE @DT nVARCHAR(MAX) = N'<Names>
    <Name></Name>
    <Name>€</Name>
    <Name>ä</Name>
    <Name>Μπανάνες</Name>
</Names>'

DECLARE @XML XML
SET @XML = @DT

SELECT @XML
```

The output is :

```
<Names>
  <Name></Name>
  <Name>€</Name>
  <Name>ä</Name>
  <Name>Μπανάνες</Name>
</Names>
```

You don't even have to use `nvarchar(max)`, you can assign a Unicode literal directly to an `XML` column or variable :

```
DECLARE @XML xml = N'<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Names>
    <Name></Name>
    <Name>€</Name>
    <Name>ä</Name>
    <Name>Μπανάνες</Name>
</Names>'

SELECT @XML
```

[Unicode types and literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) use either the full UTF-16 range or the reduced UCS-2 range, depending on whether a Supplementary Character collation is used.

If a prolog is required, remove the `encoding` attribute. The text already uses a Unicode encoding. If you try to use `utf-8` you'll get an error complaining about an attempt to switch encodings.

This will work though:

```
DECLARE @DT nVARCHAR(MAX) = N'<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Names>
    <Name></Name>
    <Name>€</Name>
    <Name>ä</Name>
    <Name>Μπανάνες</Name>
</Names>'
```